# canvas not outputting expected £ text symbol to canvas, contains an additional character

Tags: html5-canvas

When I try to write a £ sign on to canvas

```
context.fillText("£ ",600,165);
```

The output will write `Â £` to the canvas object, anyone got ideas on what to do... I tried

```
context.fillText("&pound; ",600,165);
```

but that only writes &pound to the output object.

Comment: Could be your page encoding, or browser settings. Make sure the page encoding  is set to Unicode (UTF-8). You can also try `ctx.fillText(String.fromCharCode(163),x,y)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's likely not to work if encoding of the page isn't defined. try this in the html page at the very top

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">   <!-- THIS ONE !! -->
   blabla...
```

example below show it works when it is a html5 page with utf-8

```js
document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d").fillText("£ ",10,10);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300px" height="50px">no html5 support</canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, I didn't think that it mattered as the project is not for the web its to run on a local machine as a web page without a server.

Comment: @MarkGiblin they did something funky there, i think bcos security. found this one an interesting read: https://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-character-encoding